# pygame Is there an easier way to draw rectangles?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using `pygame.draw.rect()` to draw a rectangle to the surface of my game. I want to draw various rectangles so I put the x and y coordinates as a variable (x, y, 50, 50) and add 50 to each of them every iteration. However, this draws a new rectangle and removes the old rectangle. Is there a way to make it so that the old rectangle stays while a new one is drawn?

```
x = 50
y = 50
count = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])  
running = True 
while running:  

     for event in pygame.event.get():         
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:             
               running = False      

     screen.fill((255, 255, 255))     

     pygame.draw.rect(screen, 255, (odd,even,50,50))   

     count += 1  
     if count > 100:          
         odd += 50          
         even += 50          
         count = 0

     pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code that iterates and draws your rectangles? A minimal reproducible example that can be run to recreate your error is best

Comment: @lain shelvington


`x = 50
y = 50
count = 0
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

running = True
while running:

for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, 255, (odd,even,50,50))
    if count > 100:
         odd += 50
         even += 50
         count = 0`

Comment: Add the code to the question, it's unreadable as a comment

Comment: @lain Shelvington done

Comment: You fill the screen every tick which effectively "clears" it and you draw a rectangle every 100 ticks. What is your desired result, to not clear the screen at all and add more and more rectangles to the screen every 100 ticks?

Comment: I guess so yeah

Comment: Try removing the call to `screen.fill((255, 255, 255))` from your while loop or move it to before so that the screen is only cleared at the start of your program

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 nested loops if you want to draw checkered tiles. Draw the tiles on a background surface be before the application loop and, `blit` the background surface on the screen in the application loop for best performance.

[image]

```py
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])  

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
color1 = (64, 64, 128)
color2 = (196, 128, 64)
for i in range(screen.get_width() // 50):
    for j in range(screen.get_height() // 50):
        c = color1 if (i+j) % 2 == 0 else color2
        pygame.draw.rect(background, c, (i*50, j*50, 50, 50))   

running = True 
while running:  
     for event in pygame.event.get():         
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:             
               running = False      

     screen.blit(background, (0, 0))     

     pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

See also:

- [How can i draw rectangles in multiple rows and columns in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66506971/how-can-i-draw-rectangles-in-multiple-rows-and-columns-in-pygame/66506991#66506991)
- [how do I cover a window with scalable rects in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009583/how-do-i-cover-a-window-with-scalable-rects-in-pygame)